# Is it possible to have L3 broadcasts without L2 broadcasts?

Tags: local-area-network

So, I understand that when you do an L2 broadcast (for example ARP) it only hits the L2 layer and L3 doesn't see it. But I've seen a lot of talk about L3 broadcasts and how it causes L2 broadcasts to also occur.

Is there a case where you would/can do an L3 broadcast without having an L2 broadcast also occur or are these two linked (required).

Comment: Why does this get a negative vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what layer 2 you use. *If* the layer 2 is able to broadcast on its own, delivering an L3 broadcast by L2 broadcast is the most efficient way.

*Hypothetically*, you could also send the L3 broadcast by sending individual L2 unicasts if you know all the recipients (ie. the application's broadcast is translated to unicasts the a router).

With a *layer 2 that can't broadcast*, a router would have to figure out another way to realize an L3 broadcast. E.g. a router with bunch of serial lines with PPP clients all in the same subnet has no other choice than generating individual unicasts. In practice, broadcasts don't usually work in such a scenario.

So, **yes** - L3 broadcasts without L2 broadcasts are possible yet unlikely. In a nutshell, L3 doesn't care how a broadcast is delivered in the lower layer.

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately, traffic is sent to the MAC address (physical layer) of a host. When traffic is destined for a specific layer 3 address, that address must be resolved to the unique MAC address of the intended destination host. Because there's no unique MAC address for a Layer 3 broadcast (because the broadcast is intended for all hosts in that layer 3 network) the traffic must ultimately be sent to a MAC address to which all hosts listen for traffic. This is the Layer 2 broadcast address of FF-FF-FF-FF.

So the answer is no, there isn't any way to have a Layer 3 broadcast without also having a Layer 2 broadcast. This is one of the things VLAN's address. Separating the Layer 2 broadcast domains.

**EDIT**

To address the comment regarding multiple Layer 3 networks connected to the same physical segment/switch, see the screenshot below. This is a device in the Layer 3 network 192.168.2.0/24 connected to the same physical switch and with membership in the same VLAN as hosts in the Layer 3 network 192.168.1.0/24. You can clearly see that the Layer 2 destination MAC address is FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF. All hosts connected to the same physical segment/VLAN will receive this traffic, regardless of which Layer 3 network they're in. Only the hosts in the same Layer 3 network will accept the traffic. Hosts not in the same Layer 3 network will discard this traffic, but they will receive it nonetheless. This capture was taken on a host in the 192.168.1.0/24 network... so clearly it is seeing broadcasts meant for hosts in the 192.168.2.0/24 network. The hosts in the 192.168.1.0/24 network simply discard this traffic upon receiving it.

[image]

Comment: Are you aware, that there can be more IP segments assigned? Then L3 broadcast on one IP segment won't reach all devices connected to the LAN(VLAN).